# How to change view with ajax and a toggle?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twig, drupal-8, drupal-views

On Drupal 8, I created 2 block views:

```
message_activity_stream_timeline_public
message_activity_stream_timeline_private
```

I added the following code in the TWIG template of my homepage :

```
  <div class="main-timeline">
    {{ drupal_view('message_activity_stream_timeline_public', 'block_1') }}
    {{ drupal_view('message_activity_stream_timeline_private', 'block_1') }}
  </div>
```

I do not want to display the 2 blocks at the same time I want to create a toggle button and switch from block `message_activity_stream_timeline_public` to `message_activity_stream_timeline_private` with ajax and vice versa.

How can I do this ?

**UPDATE (I found the solution) :**

```
          <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="pills-public-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-public" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-public" aria-selected="false">PUBLIC</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-private-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-private" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-private" aria-selected="true">PRIVÉ</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

and

```
  <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-public" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-public-tab">
      <div class="home-page-footer">
        <div class="timelines">
          <div class="main-timeline pt-5">
            {{ drupal_view('message_activity_stream_timeline_public', 'block_1') }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-private" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-private-tab">
      <div class="home-page-footer">
        <div class="timelines">
          <div class="main-timeline pt-5">
            {{ drupal_view('message_activity_stream_timeline_private', 'block_1') }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But tabs do not suit me. I am looking for a toggle button appearance.

I'm on Bootstrap 4 and I found this :

https://bootswatch.com/sketchy/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPoyj.png)

How should I change the first part of my code to look the same? (a button 3 times bigger would be ideal)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NVdH.png)

```
          <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="pills-public-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-public" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-public" aria-selected="false">PUBLIC</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-private-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-private" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-private" aria-selected="true">PRIVÉ</a>
            </li>
          </ul>



          <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" checked="">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Toggle this switch element</label>
          </div>



          <div class="toggle-on-off">
            <span class="toggle-on-off-public">PUBLIC</span>
            <i class="fas fa-toggle-on fa-inverse fa-rotate-180 fa-3x text-primary"></i>
            <span class="toggle-on-off-prive">PRIVÉ</span>
          </div>
```

In this screenshot, the first button (tab) is my current code and it works.

I want to use a rocker button from Bootstrap 4, this is the second button to replace the tabs.

I want to have the appearance of the third button (the text on each side).